# Searching for a method which can close, reopen an external battery every 20 mins

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino board(not an Arduino product but an electronic board which can be mounted on an Arduino Uno) which is charged by an external battery(Sony 10000mAh) for 24 hours and I want to close, reopen the battery every 20 mins. Is there any effective method and not very complicated?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'close and reopen' the battery? Unplug it and plug it back again? Are you trying to reboot the Arduino every 20 minutes?

Comment: Sorry for that if my question was not clear. Yes, just like unplug and plug again, but not by hand. In fact, it is not an Arduino board which is charged by the battery, is an another electronic board(it can be mounted on an Arduino Uno and transform the infos by I2C). This board is not stable and blocked about every 20mins. In this case, the board can not be rebooted. I recharge the board(unplug and plug the battery by hand) and it will work again... So I need a third-part switch to 'reboot' the battery in order to reboot the board.

Comment: You could use either a *relay* or a *transistor* (depending on voltage level) to switch off/on the device using an **Arduino**, using its internal clock system to get a rough *estimate* of time flow. Arduino is not very precise, but for *20 minutes* only the error should be negligible (in the magnitude of some seconds). Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relay, A relay is an electrically controlled switch, which depends on magnetic field to switch a pole between 2 positions.

All you have to do is to find a relay with voltage rating that fits the battery,

you can find many tutorials on how to use relay with arduino as in here
http://www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-a-12V-Relay-to-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS